# Is there a way to configure in Grails access to two different schemas of the database?

Tags: grails

I need to access from Grails to several different tables that are in different schemas. The user has access permissions to all the tables, but , when I try to map the Domain classses to the tables, I can't find a way to get it done.

I've tried to map the domain this way:

```
  static mapping = {
        table 'SCHEMA2.TABLE'
        //Table columns and mapping
        ...
    }
```

I can also change the default schema on the DataSource file, but in this case I keep accessing only one of the two schemas

```
  hibernate.default_schema = 'schema2'
```

We've make alias to acess the tables in schema2 from schema1, but I think there should be a way to do this, without having to define all the mapping with Hibernate (I really don't like XML files)

Comment: so why are you using two different schemes? Why not handling it like two different databases?

Comment: It's a legacy database that's make that way. I preffer to ccess them as the same database, as they really are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is old, but just in case:

you can do this in your domain class mapping section:

```
static mapping = {
    table name: "book_catalog", schema: "dbo", catalog: "CRM"
}
```

[grails guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [DataSources](http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources) plugin?   I believe it does what you are looking for - allows to configure multiple dbs and map domain objects to different databases.

I thought I saw some emails on the forum about 1.2 not working right now - definitely read through the forums to learn about issues other people may have .